# how to calculate the stock worth using a function in python

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

So I have tried running my code this far and it keeps on giving me an error. I need to calculate the total stock worth but I am stuck and really confused on how to move forward.

```
#a list of items in a cafe
cafeMenu = ["coffee, muffins, cake, tea"]

#a dictionary with integer keys
intKeys_stockDict = {coffee: '12'
                     muffins: '9'
                     cake: '10'
                     tea: '8'
                     }


#a dictionary with  keys
int_ Keys_priceDict = {coffee: '15'
                       muffins: '12'
                       cake: '11'
                       tea: '10'
                       }


def totalstock(stockworth):
```

Comment: What error is coming up? Have you added an extra space between int_ and Keys_priceDict? Or is that a typo? What is your expected output

Comment: It keeps on giving you error, because you haven't completed the `totalstock` function. Insert a `pass` as of now.

Comment: Err... 1) Welcome to StackOverflow. As you're new here, please have a read through [ask] for guidance on asking good questions. 2) One issue with your question, is the exclusion of the error you're getting. You *should* [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56293235/edit) your pasting it verbatim. 3) One syntax error is due to missing commas between key-value pairs on your dictionary. Other errors are outlined by other users above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#a list of items in a cafe
cafeMenu = ["coffee", "muffins", "cake", "tea"]

intKeys_stockDict = {"coffee": 12,
                     "muffins": 9,
                     "cake": 10,
                     "tea": 8
                     }
int_Keys_priceDict = {"coffee": 15,
                       "muffins": 12,
                       "cake": 11,
                       "tea": 10
                       }

totalstock = 0
for item in cafeMenu:
  totalstock += intKeys_stockDict[item]*int_Keys_priceDict[item]
print(totalstock)
```